# python identity matrix for loop

Tags: python

A program that will create a square matrix of any size the values on its diagonals are `1`, and the remaining values of the matrix are `0`.

```
matrix = []

dimension = int (input ("Enter matrix unit size:"))

for i in range (0, dimension):
     for j in range (0, dimension):
         if i == j:
             matrix.append (1)
         else:
             matrix.append (0)
        
print (matrix)
```

I need matrix like `[[],[],[]]`, how?
`matrix[[i]].append(1)` - doesn't work

Comment: If you are not familiar with numpy you can do this: `import numpy as np` and `np.identity(dimension)`

Comment: A square has two diagonals: one from top left to bottom right and one from bottom left to top right.. Your code fills only the first of these with ones.

Comment: @AdrianW Although the plural "diagonals" leaves this rather ambiguous, the title mentions the "identity matrix" which only has ones on the main diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert one row to `matrix` before entering the `for j` loop, and then add the element to the row, rather than to the matrix.

```
matrix = []

dimension = int(input("Enter identity matrix size:"))

for i in range(0, dimension):
     row = []
     matrix.append(row)
     for j in range(0, dimension):
         if i == j:
             row.append(1)
         else:
             row.append(0)

print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could let

```
matrix = [[1 if i == j else 0 for i in range(dimension)] for j in range(dimension)]
```

Note, though, that any sort of linear algebra will be much more conveniently carried out in NumPy/SciPy. In NumPy, for instance, the identity matrix would be produced with [`numpy.eye`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) through

```
import numpy as np
np.eye(dimension)
```

and in SciPy, using [`scipy.sparse.identity`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.identity.html),

```
from scipy.sparse import identity
identity(dimension)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

matrix = []

dimension = int (input ("Enter matrix unit size:"))

for i in range (0, dimension):
     for j in range (0, dimension):
         if i == j:
             matrix.append (1)
         else:
             matrix.append (0)

npmatrix = np.array(matrix)
npmatrix = npmatrix.reshape(dimension,dimension)
print(npmatrix)
```